# Spring - 405 Http method DELETE is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-405, http-delete

Well I have a strange problem with executing a "DELETE" HTTP request in Spring.

I have a controller method which I have mapped a DELETE request to:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{authorizationUrl}",method=DELETE)
    public void deleteAuthorizationServer(
            @RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String authorization,
            @PathVariable("authorizationUrl") String authorizationUrl)
            throws  IOException {

        System.out.println("TEST");

    }
```

The controller is mapped using `@RequestMapping("/authorization_servers");`
When I send a request through my DEV Http Client, I am getting the response : `405 Http method DELETE is not supported by this URL`.

The request looks like this:

```
 DELETE    localhost:8080/authorization_servers/asxas

  Headers:
  Authorization: "test:<stuff>"
```

**If someone can look into this and help me, I would be grateful**

Comment: What mapping do you have on the controller class itself?  Do you have an @ApplicationPath set up as well?

Comment: Thanks! I have this `@RequestMapping("/authorization_servers")`

Comment: Moved this to a comment as suggested. The method is called by Ajax, correct?

Comment: Show more from the log, error message

Comment: @geoand Nope, it's not an AJAX. It's an ordinary request

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri And what do the caller expect to see in return?

Comment: @geoand I think you're getting off topic a little bit.  If it's not mapping to the correct url, the problem lies with the mapping, not the return type.

Comment: @jgitter If you say so :)

Comment: What version of spring is this?

Comment: Hi, can you check what method you are passing while making request that is method =? , if not specified specify like method="DELETE" after form action..

Comment: What happens if you add `required=false` to `@RequestHeader`?

Comment: @KaribasappaGC It's DELETE. I just checked it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the @RequestHeader parameter?  Just curious as it may help to diagnose the issue....  Also, are you getting any errors in the log on startup?

Comment: @geoand, jgitter
I will try it and get back in a couple of moments. Thanks!

Comment: Also, could you post your Spring MVC configuration?

Comment: @geoand I am not using an xml for the configuration, I have configured it through my code itself.

Comment: @jgitter I have removed RequestHeader and it still throws the same error on me :(

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri Ok, could you post your Java Config?

Comment: Are there any other mappings in that controller that work?  Are you sure there isn't a context root?

Comment: @jgitter Yes, I have another method that is mapped like this:
` @RequestMapping(method = PUT)` public void ...<stuff>`

And it works!

Comment: And what url do you use to access that?  I'm sorry to be asking obvious questions, but when we figure this out, I sense it will be a /facepalm moment.

Comment: @jgitter No problem, that is exactly how I trackback too. This is how I am calling the other method that works:
`localhost:8080/authorization_servers/`

Comment: Update: I got rid of the value="/{authorizationUrl}" attribute to test if it even works straight with the /authorization_servers mapping. No wonder, it still doesn't.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{authorizationUrl}", method = DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public void deleteAuthorizationServer(
    @RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String authorization,
    @PathVariable("authorizationUrl") String authorizationUrl
){
    System.out.printf("Testing: You tried to delete %s using %s\n", authorizationUrl, authorization);
}
```

You were missing @ResponseBody. Your method was actually getting called; it was what happened after that that was producing the error code.

Comment: *groan* Can't believe I missed that

Comment: This really shouldn't give a 405. If it does, it is a bug with Spring.

Comment: it is not working for me :/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471604/getting-405-request-method-get-not-supported-when-calling-method-delete

Answer (score 6):

If the `@RequestMapping` pattern doesn't match or is *invalid*, it results in a 404 not found. However, if it happens to match another mapping with a different method (ex. GET), it results in this `405 Http method DELETE is not supported`.

My issue was just like this one, except my requestMapping was the cause. It was this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = { "/thing/{id:\\d+" }, method = { RequestMethod.DELETE })
```

Do you see it?  The inner closing brace is missing, it should be: `{ "/thing/{id:\\d+}" }`  The `\\d+` is a regular expression to match 1 or more numeric digits.  The braces delimit the parameter in the path for use with `@PathVariable`.

Since it's invalid it can't match my DELETE request:
http://example.com/thing/33
which would have resulted in a 404 not found error, however, I had another mapping for GET:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = { "/thing/{id:\\d+}" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET })
```

Since the brace pattern is correct, but it's not a method DELETE, then it gave a error 405 method not supported.

Comment: This was helpful, Thanks. Whoever read this, check your brackets !!

Comment: Also check for mapping in my case I had 2 controller with mapping like ```/contacts/{id} DELETE`` and "/contacts GET" so when I called my DELETE Endpoint with {id} pathVariable as empty url got matched to my /contacts/ GET endpoint, giving 405

Answer (score 4):

Your annotation should look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{authorizationUrl}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
```

I don't know where you got that DELETE variable from.  :-)

Comment: OP probably has used static imports for DELETE. But if not, good catch!

Comment: Thank you for your time, however I did static import DELETE from spring:
`import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.DELETE;`

Comment: Blast!  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to return `ResponseEntity<Void>` (with custom response status) instead of setting custom response status on `HttpServletResponse` (from endpoint method param).

ex: http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2016/02/response-for-get-post-put-delete-in-rest.html

Answer (score 0):

also make sure you're calling it with `"Content-Type" header="text/html"`. If not, then change it or specify it in the `requestMapping`. If it doesn't match, you get the same 405.