Spring Delete method not supported
I have a problem with the delete method. Other methods are okay, but there is something wrong with delete. It shows me: Request method 'DELETE' is not supported.
My request to Postman is http://localhost:8080/v1/tasks/1 with a delete option. Any ideas?
@Service
public class DbService {
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository repository;

    public void deleteTask(final Long id) throws TaskNotFoundException {
        Task task = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(TaskNotFoundException::new);
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }

Interface
@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Long> {

    @Override
    void deleteById(Long id);

}

Controller
@DeleteMapping(value = {"taskId"})
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteTask(@PathVariable Long taskId) throws TaskNotFoundException {
    service.deleteTask(taskId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Deleted succesfully" + taskId);
}


@DeleteMapping(value = {"taskId"}) looks incorrect… How about @DeleteMapping("/{taskId}") or even @DeleteMapping("/tasks/{taskId}")? Have you tried those?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349871/spring-405-http-method-delete-is-not-supported-by-this-url

I think what you have written should work. I created a similar case and it ran fine for me. Please check the code here https://github.com/rootExplorr/TestRepo1/tree/master/sof
Just compare with the code in the repo and check what is different from your code.

To call your controller by this url
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/v1/tasks/1

You need:
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{taskId}")

and not
@DeleteMapping(value = {"taskId"})

/{taskId}: This tells Spring that the endpoint accepts a dynamic path variable, which will be passed as the taskId parameter.
I assume that your controller looks like:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/tasks")
public class TaskController {


I dont thing that is the issue. Please check here: https://github.com/rootExplorr/TestRepo1/tree/master/sof
This code works for me.
